# Last index of object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Code below will return me the first index of the object with id = "1" which is 0. How to find the last index of the object with id = "1" which is 2 ? Of course I could use a loop but without using a loop is it possible?

```
var array = [{id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: "1"}];

    var index = array.findIndex(function(oItem) {
        return oItem.id === "1";
    });
```

Comment: you could use recursion....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `map()` you array to just array of ids and then use `lastIndexOf`

```js
var array = [{id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: "1"}];

var lastIndex = array.map(e => e.id).lastIndexOf('1')
console.log(lastIndex)
```

Since currently there is no `findLastIndex` method and you don't want to use loop you could create your own function using recursion that you can pass anonymous function as parameter to search by.

```js
var array = [{id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: "1"}];

function findLastIndex(data, func) {
  var start = data.length - 1;
  var result = null;

  function search(data, i, func) {
    if (i < 0) return;
    var check = func(data[i]);

    if (check == true) {
      result = i;
      return;
    }
    search(data, i -= 1, func)
  }

  search(data, start, func)
  return result;
}

var lastIndex = findLastIndex(array, function(e) {
  return e.id == 1;
})

console.log(lastIndex)
```

Comment: From the OP: *"Of course I could use a loop but without using a loop is it possible?"*

Comment: @Mike McCaughan Updated my answer.

Comment: Looks tidy. Just not sure why ESLint complains: ESLint(syntax-parse): Unexpected token >

Comment: `lastIndexOf` is still a loop. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf. Anyways I highly doubt that it can be done without loop, actually.

Comment: I am quite new to Javascript coming from ABAP background. It looks to me like all the operations done on arrays are based on looping through them. Are there any binary searches on arrays out of the box?

Comment: @Kinduser Please update the link to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf

Comment: @strah Accident (:

Comment: @Kinduser: I'm afraid `indexOf` is _also_ a loop. If you want O(1) performance, use a hash table or other kinds of direct index by the attribute(s) you're looking for.

Comment: @9000 `map` is also a loop, isn't it?

Comment: @Kinduser: _All_ ways to access an array element except by its index will end up with a loop.

Comment: Nice functional solution. Short circuits the search. I might make it a bit shorter and cleaner by returning the index without using a closure: https://jsfiddle.net/193tbp7k/

Comment: @Radek: You've said you don't want a loop. Are you really saying you don't want a linear search? You mentioned a binary search. That'll only work if the array is sorted by the term you're searching. What is the ultimate use? Is there a reason you need to store them in an Array? Is it a large array?

Comment: @squint From the clean code point of view map looks much nicer than a loop even though from performance point of view are similar. I am using a SAPUI5/OPENUI5 framework. My data is stored in a JSON model. And model.getData() returns the data in an array format for manipulation. The array shouldn't be too big ~ 200-300 entries. I would do with a better option than sequential scan as I find myself calling these .map and .findIndex in a loop which is not a good thing. And I am fine with sorted array

Comment: @Radek: Then if you sorted the array, you could do the binary search. There's nothing built in, so you'll need to write one. But if you don't ultimately need them to be kept in an Array, then once you get the data, you could convert it to a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), where the key is the ID and the value is an array of matches for that ID. If you need lookups on other properties too, then you'll want to take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array#map` and declare new `index` variable, which would be overwrited until it reaches the last element with given `id`.

```js
var array = [{id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: "1"}],
    index;
    arr = array.map((v,i) => v.id == 1 ? index = i : null);
    
    console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using [**Array map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method **:**

```js
var myarray = [{id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: "1"}];

var res = myarray.map(function(item) {
  return item.id;
});

console.log(res.lastIndexOf("1"));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind using lodash, it has [`findLastIndex`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#findLastIndex).

If anything, you can look at [the source of it](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/findLastIndex.js) for ideas.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess suggesting a library where at worst a loop would do is a bit overkill.

Comment: @strah: This is a kind of library you end up using anyway in most projects — but not necessarily. This is why it starts with an "If". Unfortunately, the standard Array object lacks an efficient method for that. A library may pick the most perfromant way for a particular environment, though, should it exist.